# Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая перед словом "информация"?

Tags: запятые

*При этом сразу после вывода результатов оценок(,) информация, подтвержденная комиссией, направляется в электронном виде в аккаунты сотрудников организаций, прошедших оценку.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, оборот с "после" не надо обособлять.

Ещё меня смущает словосочетание "результатов баллов". Если бы было, например, "количества баллов", или "результатов теста", я бы понял.